# How to add tcp6 on raspbian?

Tags: linux

You have no necessity to install any additional packages. Everything should work fine. Thus check whether files /proc/net/tcp6, /proc/net/tcp exist. If they are absent, just add them.  you gave this answer at given link:https://serverfault.com/questions/425345/why-dstat-failed-with-tcp-option how to add tcp6 on raspbian.

Comment: Before trying any other site, learn how [SE] works, though. We are not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/net/tcp6` is not a regular file, you can't create it like a regular file (e.g. with `touch /proc/net/tcp6`) as was suggested in the question you're linking to.

`/proc/net/tcp6` is a kernel interface that is created when your kernel has IPv6 support enabled. To enable that the typical solution is to load the corresponding kernel module in your running kernel with `modprobe -i ipv6`.